# Mysql Connector issue in Python

Tags: python, pip, mariadb, centos7

I have installed MySQL connector for python 3.6 in centos 7
If I search for installed modules with below command

> it's showing as below
>       pip3.6 freeze
>       mysql-connector==2.1.6
>       mysql-connector-python==2.1.7
>       pymongo==3.6.1
>
> pip3.6 search mysql-connector
>      mysql-connector-python (8.0.6)   -MYSQL driver written in Python
>      INSTALLED: 2.1.7
>      LATEST:    8.0.6
>      mysql-connector (2.1.6)      - MySQL driver written in Python
>      INSTALLED: 2.1.6 (latest)

MySQL connector installed.But when trying to run the program using MySQL connector then its showing error no module installed MySQL connector.I am using MariaDB 10.0

> python3.6 mysql1.py
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "mysql1.py", line 2, in 
>       import mysql.connector as mariadb
>       File "/root/Python_environment/my_Scripts/mysql.py", line 2, in 
>       import mysql.connector
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package

can any one know how to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem I faced in Environment created by python.Outside the python environment i am able to run the script.Its running succefully.In python environment i am not able run script i am working on it.if any body know can give suggestion on this

Answer (score 1):

You must not name your script `mysql.py` — in that case Python tries to import `mysql` from the script — and fails.

Rename your script `/root/Python_environment/my_Scripts/mysql.py` to something else.